# How can I increase the number of photos Prompto can take?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

As it currently stands, Prompto can only capture 10 or so photos between rest times. When I rest every couple of hours, this isn't an issue and I can get some good shots in that time frame. On the other hand, there have been times where I go a few in-game days without resting and had the potential to get some great shots, but was hindered by only having photos of the first day or two.

How can I increase the number of photos Prompto can take? If so, is there a maximum limit this can be increased to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5fs6qd/a_few_tricks_for_ff15/dav6kr3/), it appears that the [Snapshot](http://ff15wiki.com/wiki/Snapshot) Ascension skill will allow you to take up to 5 additional pictures on top of the base 10. Additionally, the [Camera Strap](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Camera+Strap) accessory will *also* increase the number of photographs Prompto will be able to share with you at each rest stop by 5.

Thus, you will be able to take a maximum of **20** pictures per rest.

However, as Snapshot is a Technique that requires usage of the Tech bar that only builds during battle, 5 of your 20 pictures will always be from during a battle (as opposed to just ambient images of your group during your travels).